# Помогите собрать Qt под Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, сборка, raspbian

Хочу собрать Qt на Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB). Делаю по руководству [Building Qt 5.12 LTS for Raspberry Pi on Raspbian](https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-512-raspberry-pi). Пробовал и для 5.12.7/5.12.8. Результат одинаковый.
Вот что я делал:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.8/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8.tar.xz
md5sum qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8.tar.xz
tar xf qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8.tar.xz
git clone https://github.com/oniongarlic/qt-raspberrypi-configuration.git
# в скачанном выше проекте изменил версию 5.12.7 -> 5.12.8
cd qt-raspberrypi-configuration && make install DESTDIR=../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libfontconfig1-dev libdbus-1-dev libfreetype6-dev libicu-dev libinput-dev libxkbcommon-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libglib2.0-dev libraspberrypi-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev libmariadbclient-dev bluez libbluetooth-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-alsa libasound2-dev pulseaudio libpulse-dev libcups2-dev libwayland-dev libx11-dev libxcb1-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxext-dev libatspi-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libgbm-dev
mkdir ../build
cd ../build

PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig \
../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8/configure -platform linux-rpi4-v3d-g++ \
-v \
-opengl es2 -eglfs \
-no-gtk \
-opensource -confirm-license -release \
-reduce-exports \
-force-pkg-config \
-nomake examples -no-compile-examples \
-skip qtwayland \
-skip qtwebengine \
-no-feature-geoservices_mapboxgl \
-qt-pcre \
-no-pch \
-ssl \
-evdev \
-system-freetype \
-fontconfig \
-glib \
-prefix /opt/Qt5.12 \
-qpa eglfs
```

Получаю отчет, где `EGLFS EGLDevice NO`:

```
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Build type: linux-rpi4-v3d-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Compiler: gcc 8.3.0
Configuration: use_gold_linker enable_new_dtags largefile neon shared rpath release c++11 c++14 c++1z concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++1z
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using gold linker ...................... yes
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. no
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Build parts ............................ libs tools
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
  DTLS ................................... yes
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  EGL .................................... yes
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ yes
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... yes
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. yes
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. yes
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... yes
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... no
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ yes
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
  Mir client ............................. no
  XCB:
    Using system-provided XCB libraries .. no
    XCB XKB .............................. yes
    XCB XInput ........................... yes
    Native painting (experimental) ....... no
    GL integrations:
      GLX Plugin ......................... no
      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... yes
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... yes
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. yes
  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
Further Image Formats:
  JasPer ................................. no
  MNG .................................... no
  TIFF ................................... yes
    Using system libtiff ................. yes
  WEBP ................................... yes
    Using system libwebp ................. no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. yes
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... yes
  Linux Crypto API ....................... yes
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. no
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... yes
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. yes
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt Tools:
  QDoc ................................... no

Note: Disabling X11 Accessibility Bridge: D-Bus or AT-SPI is missing.

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.

Either ensure that llvm-config is in your PATH environment variable, or set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
On Windows, you must set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/opt/Qt5.12'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

И при попытке сборки получаю ошибку:

```
.obj/qsgbatchrenderer.o:qsgbatchrenderer.cpp:function QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::map(QSGBatchRenderer::Buffer*, int, bool): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::separateIndexBuffer() const'
.obj/qsgbatchrenderer.o:qsgbatchrenderer.cpp:function QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::uploadBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::separateIndexBuffer() const'
.obj/qsgbatchrenderer.o:qsgbatchrenderer.cpp:function QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::visualizeBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::separateIndexBuffer() const'
.obj/qsgbatchrenderer.o:qsgbatchrenderer.cpp:function QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderMergedBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch const*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::separateIndexBuffer() const'
.obj/qsgtexture.o:qsgtexture.cpp:function QSGPlainTexture::bind(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::from(QOpenGLContext*)'
.obj/qsgrenderloop.o:qsgrenderloop.cpp:function QSGRenderLoop::instance(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGWindowsRenderLoop::QSGWindowsRenderLoop()'
.obj/qsgdefaultglyphnode_p.o:qsgdefaultglyphnode_p.cpp:function QSGTextMaskMaterial::updateCache(QFontEngine::GlyphFormat): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::from(QOpenGLContext*)'
.obj/qsgdefaultcontext.o:qsgdefaultcontext.cpp:function QSGDefaultContext::createRenderContext(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultRenderContext::QSGDefaultRenderContext(QSGContext*)'
.obj/qsgdefaultcontext.o:qsgdefaultcontext.cpp:function QSGDefaultContext::createLayer(QSGRenderContext*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGDefaultLayer::QSGDefaultLayer(QSGRenderContext*)'
.obj/qsgthreadedrenderloop.o:qsgthreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGThreadedRenderLoop::windowDestroyed(QQuickWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for QSGRenderThread'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
.obj/qsgthreadedrenderloop.o:qsgthreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGThreadedRenderLoop::handleExposure(QQuickWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for QSGRenderThread'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
.obj/qsgthreadedrenderloop.o:qsgthreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGRenderThread::~QSGRenderThread(): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for QSGRenderThread'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
.obj/qsgthreadedrenderloop.o:qsgthreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGRenderThread::~QSGRenderThread(): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for QSGRenderThread'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
.obj/qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.o:qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.cpp:function QSGSoftwareInternalImageNode::setTexture(QSGTexture*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareLayer::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.o:qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.cpp:function QSGSoftwareInternalImageNode::pixmap() const: error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.o:qsgsoftwareinternalimagenode.cpp:function QSGSoftwareInternalImageNode::pixmap() const: error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareLayer::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.o:qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.cpp:function QSGSoftwareNinePatchNode::setTexture(QSGTexture*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.o:qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.cpp:function QSGSoftwareImageNode::updateCachedMirroredPixmap(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.o:qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.cpp:function QSGSoftwareImageNode::updateCachedMirroredPixmap(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareLayer::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.o:qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.cpp:function QSGSoftwareImageNode::paint(QPainter*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.o:qsgsoftwarepublicnodes.cpp:function QSGSoftwareImageNode::paint(QPainter*): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareLayer::staticMetaObject'
.obj/qsgsoftwarepainternode.o:qsgsoftwarepainternode.cpp:function QSGSoftwarePainterNode::update(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture::QSGSoftwarePixmapTexture(QPixmap const&)'
.obj/qsgsoftwareadaptation.o:qsgsoftwareadaptation.cpp:function QSGSoftwareAdaptation::create(QString const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareContext::QSGSoftwareContext(QObject*)'
.obj/qsgsoftwareadaptation.o:qsgsoftwareadaptation.cpp:function QSGSoftwareAdaptation::createWindowManager(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareRenderLoop::QSGSoftwareRenderLoop()'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::createRenderContext(QSGContext*) const: error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareRenderContext::QSGSoftwareRenderContext(QSGContext*)'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::~QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop(): error: undefined reference to 'QSG_RASTER_LOG_RENDERLOOP()'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::~QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop(): error: undefined reference to 'QSG_RASTER_LOG_RENDERLOOP()'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::show(QQuickWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QSG_RASTER_LOG_RENDERLOOP()'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::show(QQuickWindow*): error: undefined reference to 'QSG_RASTER_LOG_RENDERLOOP()'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop::QSGSoftwareThreadedRenderLoop(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareContext::QSGSoftwareContext(QObject*)'
.obj/qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.o:qsgsoftwarethreadedrenderloop.cpp:function QSGSoftwareContext::createRenderContext(): error: undefined reference to 'QSGSoftwareRenderContext::QSGSoftwareRenderContext(QSGContext*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:955: ../../lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.12.8] Ошибка 1
make[3]: выход из каталога «/home/pi/qt/qt_5_12_8/build/qtdeclarative/src/quick»
make[2]: *** [Makefile:99: sub-quick-make_first-ordered] Ошибка 2
make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/pi/qt/qt_5_12_8/build/qtdeclarative/src»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:50: sub-src-make_first] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/pi/qt/qt_5_12_8/build/qtdeclarative»
make: *** [Makefile:335: module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Ошибка 2
```

Comment: инструкция для Stretch, а у вас наверное Buster, беспроблемно собираются только редкие пары Qt-Raspbian, остальное надо допиливать или подбирать конфигурацию, и ещё имейте ввиду, что никакие clean config в реальности не работают, для пересборки надо всё стирать и распаковывать по новой

Comment: так вы что хотите собрать без X11? Это ещё проблемнее, вот инструкция - https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

Comment: @PavelGridin на сколько знаю на pi 4 не работают драйвера от Broadcom. Поэтому эта инструкция не заработает на pi 4

Comment: Если вдруг сумеете найти кого-то у кого есть платная лицензия на Embedded Qt, там есть логи по сборке, в них опции конфига, думаю должна быть и сборка для RPi

Comment: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ такое нашел

Comment: это сборка под X11, без X11 должен быть на базе VC4, а не mesa

Comment: Попробуй вот эту инструкцию, вроде бы все расписано: https://annimon.com/article/3783